# Use congruence's to find the reminder when $2^{50}$ and $41^{65}$ are divided by $7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, congruence-relations

Use congruence's to find the reminder when $2^{50}$ and $41^{65}$ are divided by 7

$2^{50}$

$50=(7)^2+1$

$2^{50}=2^{7\cdot7+1}$

and I'm not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, $$\begin{align} & 2^3\equiv 1 \pmod7 \\ \implies & (2^3)^{16}\equiv 1^{16} \pmod7 \\ \implies & 2^{48}\equiv 1 \pmod7 \\ \implies & 2^{48}\cdot 2^2\equiv 1\cdot 2^2 \pmod7 \\ \implies & \color{blue}{2^{50}\equiv 4 \pmod7}\end{align}$$

Also note that $$\begin{align} & 41\equiv -1\pmod7 \\ \implies & 41^{65}\equiv (-1)^{65}\equiv -1\pmod7 \\ \implies & \color{blue}{41^{65}\equiv 6\pmod7}\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get from the second to last line to the last line. You just add 7 to the -1 to get the 6?

Comment: You way of formatting, with all those ",\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,", was weird, and I got rid of all of those.  Even if you couldn't use alignment tabs (as I did) to get the sort of alignment you seemed to intend, you could use phantoms. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$\color\red{2^3}\equiv\color\red{1}\pmod7\implies$

$2^{50}\equiv2^{3\cdot16+2}\equiv(\color\red{2^3})^{16}\cdot2^2\equiv\color\red{1}^{16}\cdot2^2\equiv1\cdot4\equiv4\pmod7$

---

$\color\red{41}\equiv\color\red{-1}\pmod7\implies$

$\color\red{41}^{65}\equiv(\color\red{-1})^{65}\equiv(-1)\equiv6\pmod7$