# $7\mid5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2}$; $43\mid6^{n+2}+7^{2n+1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, congruence-relations

Use congruences to demonstrate
$$7\mid5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2}$$
$$43\mid6^{n+2}+7^{2n+1}$$
When you are trying to see if something is divisible by 7, 8 or any number, do you automatically use that number as the modulus?

Comment: No effort?${}{}$

Comment: just compute the value $\pmod 7$  and  $\pmod {43}$ remark cyclicity etc...

Comment: Hint: $5^2\equiv 2^5 \pmod 7$, so you can factor its $n$th power out of the sum. Similarly $6\equiv 7^2\pmod{43}$.

Comment: I answered [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942297/131263) which showed a small yet reasonable amount of effort, but this is not a 'do my homework for free' service. Please show your effort if you're expecting others to make an effort for you.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel : The proper notation is $3\mid 6$ (coded as 3 \mid 6), not $3|6. \qquad$

Comment: @barak manos I'm sure you could tell by my previous question which was much easier than this one, that I have no idea what I am doing with congruence's yet. A hint or step in the right direction is better than a reprimand. And this isn't HW BTW, I am trying to prep for an exam.

Comment: @ntgootadmth Henning Makholm's hint is sufficient for you to complete this exercise.

Comment: I understand that $5^2≡2^5$ (mod 7) but I don't see how to get to that point..

$$5^{2n}+3*2^{5n-2}$$

$$=5^{2n}+3*2^{5n}*2^{-2}$$



and then I am not sure where to go from here..

Comment: $\equiv 2^{5n}+3*2^{5n}*2^{-2}=2^{5n-1}(2^5+24)=2^{5n-1}*56 \pmod 7$

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by induction too ! (assuming that you are familiar with induction )

For the first one , assume P(n) to be true.

P(n+1) : $25.5^{2n }+ 3.2^{(5n-2)}.2^5 $which is congruent to $4.5^{2n }+ 3.2^{(5n-2)}.4 $which is divisible by 7 due to our hypothesis ( just take 4 outside).

For the second one , note  that $ 6^{(n+2)}= -7.6^n ( mod 43 )$

So it suffices to show that $43| 7(7^{2n}-6^n)$

Again note that 43 and 7 are co prime and hence if we show that $7^{2n}=6^n( mod 43) $then we are done .

Again assume P(n) : $ 43 | 7^{2n}-6^n  $ to be true

P(n+1) : $  43| 49.7^{2n }-6.6^n $ .Note that 49 = 6 ( mod 43) hence take 6 outside and the result immediately follows.

Comment: Yeah I have seen the inductive solution but I was trying to go through the congruence route, I am just not sure how

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem only using congruence. Such problems are most easily solved using induction ( and you have little bits of congruence in the inductive proof too ! )

Answer (score 2):

I will show you for $7\mid5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2}$,same is for $43$

$gcd(7,5)=1\Rightarrow \phi(7)=6\Rightarrow5^{6}\equiv1\pmod7$

$gcd(2,5)=1\Rightarrow \phi(7)=6\Rightarrow2^{6}\equiv1\pmod7$
$$5^{2n}\equiv(5^{2})^{n}\equiv25^{n}\equiv4^{n}\equiv2^{2n}\pmod{7}$$
$2^{2n}\pmod{7}$ is cyclic:
$$(n=1):2^{2}\equiv4\pmod{7}\\(n=2):2^{4}\equiv16\equiv2\pmod{7}\\(n=3):2^{6}\equiv64\equiv1\pmod{7}\\(n=4):2^{8}\equiv256\equiv4\pmod{7}\\(n=5):2^{10}\equiv1024\equiv2\pmod{7}\\(n=6):2^{12}\equiv4096\equiv1\pmod{7}$$
you see the pattern.

so:
$if(n=3k=3t+3)\Rightarrow 2n=6k$
$$2^{6k}\equiv 2^{6k}\pmod{7}\equiv (2^{6})^{k}\equiv 1^{k}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$$
$$$$
$if(n=3k+1)\Rightarrow 2n=6k+2$
$$2^{6k+2}\equiv 2^{6k}\cdot2^{2}\pmod{7} \equiv [2^{6k}\pmod{7}\cdot2^{2}\pmod{7}] \\\equiv[(2^{6})^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot4\pmod{7}]\equiv[1^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot4\pmod{7}]\equiv4\pmod{7}$$
$$$$
$if(n=3k+2)\Rightarrow 2n=6k+4$
$$2^{6k+4}\equiv 2^{6k}\cdot2^{4}\pmod{7} \equiv [2^{6k}\pmod{7}\cdot2^{4}\pmod{7}] \\\equiv[(2^{6})^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot16\pmod{7}]\equiv[1^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot2\pmod{7}]\equiv2\pmod{7}$$

$$$$
Now we deal with:  $3\cdot2^{5n-2}$

$if(n=3k=3t+3)\Rightarrow 5n-2=5(3t+3)-2=15t+1$
$$3\cdot2^{15t+1}\equiv 3\cdot2^{12t}\cdot2^{3t}\cdot2^{1}\equiv [3\pmod{7}\cdot2^{12t}\pmod{7}\cdot2^{3t}\pmod{7}\cdot2\pmod{7}]\\\equiv [3\cdot(2^{6})^{2t}\pmod{7}\cdot(2^{3})^{t}\pmod{7}\cdot2]\equiv [3\cdot1\cdot(8)^{t}\pmod{7}\cdot2]\equiv[3\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2]\equiv6\pmod{7}
$$

so:  $1+6\equiv0\pmod{7}$
$$$$
$if(n=3k+1)$
$$3\cdot2^{5n-2}\equiv 3\cdot2^{2n}\cdot2^{3n-2}\equiv [3\pmod{7}\cdot4\pmod{7}\cdot2^{9k+1}\pmod{7}]\\\equiv [3\cdot4\cdot2^{3k}\pmod{7}\cdot2^{6k}\pmod{7}\cdot2^{1}\pmod{7}]\equiv\\ [3\cdot4\cdot(8)^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot(2^{6})^{k}\pmod{7}\cdot2]\equiv[3\cdot4\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2]\equiv3\pmod{7}
$$

so:  $4+3\equiv0\pmod{7}$
$$$$
$if(n=3k+2)\Rightarrow 5n-2=2n+2n+n-2=2n+2n+3k+2-2=2n+2n+3k$
$$3\cdot2^{5n-2}\equiv 3\cdot2^{2n}\cdot2^{2n}\cdot2^{3k}\equiv [3\pmod{7}\cdot2\pmod{7}\cdot2\pmod{7}\cdot(8)^{k}\pmod{7}]\\\equiv [3\cdot2\cdot2\cdot1]\equiv5\pmod{7}
$$

so:  $2+5\equiv0\pmod{7}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2} &= (7-2)^{2n}+ 3 \cdot 2^{3(n-1)} \cdot 2^{2n+1} \\
&= ((-2)^{2n} + 3 \cdot 8^{n-1} \cdot 2^{2n+1}) \mod 7 \\
&= ((-2)^{2n} + 3 \cdot  2 \cdot 2^{2n})\mod 7 \\
&= 2^{2n}(1+6) \mod 7 \\
&= 0 \mod 7
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
6^{n+2}+7^{2n+1} &= (6^{n+2} + 7 \cdot  49^n) \mod 43 \\
&= (36 \cdot 6^n + 7 \cdot 6^n) \mod 43 \\
&= 6^n (36+7) \mod 43 \\
&= 0 \mod 43
\end{align*}